# What is the inhibitory classifier or inhibitory-SVM?

Tags: classification, svm

I want to implement Inhibitory SVM classifier in [chapter 3 of this paper](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/14/10/19336)  with scikit lib in Python.

However, it is hard to find materials that explains inhibitory-SVM or classifier.

In the paper, they explains inhibitory SVM but, I can't understand that.

I want to know I-SVM in terms of shape of input of data and label

and difference btw SVM and I-SVM.

What is the inhibitory classifier or inhibitory-SVM?

Thank you.